# Getting column parameter doesn't exist error in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata-sql-assistant

```
update t1
from 
table1 t1,
table2 t2
set
t1.active_ind=0,
t1.row_status_cd='L'
where
t2.col1
is NULL
```

Getting "Column/ parameter table 1.t1 doesnt exists" error in Teradata SQL though those fields are available in t1 . can anybody help me to resolve this please?

Comment: @marc_s actually their manual writes that so and only so joins aren't supported

Comment: @nbk: shame on anyone who builds a system that doesn't support SQL-92 JOIN syntax!

Comment: @marc_s yes that is true, tehre are many limitation in teradata , that makes the live even more compicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you only have to update table1 you don't need the t1 before the columnnames in tne `SET`, that is why you get the error.

but shouldn't there be a relation between table1 and table2, but as always you should test this first before using it, that wquery could have unforseen side effects

```
update t1
from 
    table1 t1,
    table2 t2
set
    active_ind=0,
    row_status_cd='L'
where
    t2.col1 is NULL
```